# Using Python3: how to get a boolean statement for numbers in a list being divisible by 3

Tags: python-3.x, modulo

I am running my code through an example set: [9,20,2,3]
I have been using the modulo operator (%) and my code is:

```
if index < len(the_list):
        for m in the_list:
            print(m)
            if m % 3 == 0:
                a = True
            else:
                a = False
            return a
    else:
        return False

Args:
        the_list (list): The input list
        index (int): The index

    Returns:
        _type_: True: if the value is divisible by 3, 
                False: if the value is not divisible by 3,
                False: if the index is invalid
```

One additional condition I must include is if the index position is larger than the length of the list to return False, but I believe I already have that properly integrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, just replace *myList* with your actual list

```
myList = [9,20,2,3]
finalList = []

for x in myList:
    if x % 3 == 0:
        finalList.append(True)
    else:
        finalList.append(False)

print(finalList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a list comprehension.

```
[(num%3 == 0) for num in myList]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a function that could help you :

```
def divisible_by_three(numbers):
for number in numbers:
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I had a code exactly like this and for some reason it did not run through all the items in the list. I am not sure why but it just ran through the first item in the list as long as the index position was not longer than the len(list)

Comment: The reason it did not work is that it returns immediately with either False or True, it does not iterate through the list